# What's the best approach to completely migrate from bootstrap top angular-material

Tags: angular, angular-material

What should be best approach to migrate from bootstrap to angular-material completely. I have existing project which is on bootstrap, I changed all the component css and html into angular-material(Ts not written yet). 
But while I run the application I am getting issue because of bootstrap and angular-material overriding each other.

What approach should I follow so that I can completely remove bootstrap from the application?

Comment: did you find answer to this?  can you provide us with how did you do this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, find for what elements is bootstrap still used, labels,grid, container/container-fluid class and see how they change to material one. 
If you dont like the view change of the elements, keep the bootstrap css and rewrite it do styles.css or at some components css.
(I've saved only bs-grid, it's simple easy changeable)

Second, find how you implement bootstrap to your application,
for example: installed to node-modules, or as an external stylesheet which is probably the one most common,
Go to `index.html` and remove all link rel which have bootstrap ,for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

After that you'll gone stay only with your own css and material one so watch for the differences you're going to have (BS-grid to material-grid) etc.
Good luck.